# Is there a way to define a method that will accept one parameter or none at all

Tags: ruby

I was writing a program such that it checks if a file is passed in as argument to a method or function, if no argument is passed then it accepts string through gets. I know about the * operator, but as i said i dont need an array of arguments. Either one or none and also no defaults. Is there any way thats possible ?

Comment: Why are you refusing to have `*`? Something wrong with that?

Comment: Also, a param with default `nil` value is also a good choice.

Comment: "Either one or none and also no defaults" What is with the stringent requirements?

Comment: @DamienRoche: homework assignment? They are supposed to make people think. :)

Comment: I was just curious if there is a way. Ruby is just so much full of surprises, so i  was wondering if there is any such way least heard of that anybody know.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it got me asking questions, so guess it was a good thing.

Comment: Now you can do it.. :)

Answer (score 6):

An optional argument can be simulated by a default value:

```
def my_method(arg = nil)
  #do something with arg
end
```

You can call it as `my_method()` or `my_method(arg)`. If the parameter isn't given, it's the same as if you passed in a nil value. Though I recommend a more meaningful default value if possible.

If you want a truly optional parameter, yet still require raising an exception when it is called with too many, you can use the splat and insert a guard clause:

```
def my_method(*args)
  raise ArgumentError if args.length > 1
  #do something with args.first
end
```

This way it behaves exactly the way you describe.

Comment: The thing is i don't want to use splat as it makes the argument an array. Don't you think an array is too much for a single or no piece of data. :)

Comment: You can deal with `args.first` as if it was the optional parameter. It will either be nil or the passed-in value. Personally, I prefer the default value solution.

Answer (score 3):

If there is a value that an argument never takes, say `nil`, then, you can use that as a default value:

```
def foo arg = nil
  if arg.nil?
    # argument was not given
  else
    # argument was given
  end
end
```

You can define your original module as a constant, which may free you from such restriction:

```
module NeverUsedValue; end
def foo arg = NeverUsedValue
  if arg == NeverUsedValue
    # argument was not given
  else
    # argument was given
  end
end
```

Otherwise, there is probably no way to do it without using the splat.

```
def foo *args
  case args.length
  when 1
    # argument was given
    arg = args.first
  when 0
    # argument was not given
  end
end
```

I don't know why you are refusing to use the splat. The solution using is free of the restriction, and is hence better.

Comment: I had implemented the first methods already, what i was looking for was something inbuilt if there is. Like * for multiple argument. Thanks for the answer anyway. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little abuse of default parameter. Don't try this at home.

```
def foo(bar = gets)
  puts "Got this: #{bar}"
end

foo('a param')
foo
```

#### Output

```
% ruby script.rb
Got this: a param
from gets
Got this: from gets
```